# How can I display fields from a model using django-filter?

Tags: django, filter, django-forms, django-views, django-filter

I am new to Django and I am using Django-filter to filter out blog posts when the user selects "genre". For example:- my genre has these data - horror, thriller, fantasy, and action.

I want these genres to show up as buttons on the webpage. But, I don't know why it only shows up as a text box expecting input from me to input the genre and then pulls out the post according to that.

**Update: I am not looking for the blog post to show up on click on a genre. I only want the genres to show up as buttons. That is all.**

Code mentioned below for your reference please:

filter.py

```
class GenreFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
class Meta:
    model = Genre
    fields = ['title']
```

Models.py

```
class Genre(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Views.py

```
def post_list(request):
genre_list = Genre.objects.all() 
genre_filter = GenreFilter(request.GET, queryset=genre_list)
return render(request, 'post_list.html', {'sfilter': genre_filter})
```

post_list.html

```
 <div class="genreDiv">
  {{ sfilter.form.title }}
 </div>
```

This must be a very beginner question but I am coming from a front-end environment and this is my first time making a website dynamic.

Hope to hear from you all soon.

Comment: If you want your genres to be buttons, what exactly would you like these buttons to be doing? I guess you probably want <selector>, rathan buttons?

Comment: I want to click on each button and pull the blog posts according to the button. Right now, I was able to show the genres in <selector> as well and it brings the result upon clicking the submit button.

I only want the genres to show up as buttons, that's all! I tried Django Widgets but not sure how to achieve that.

Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

In this case each button needs to be a submit button in it’s own form, like in this solution:
[django-filter button in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49349642/django-filter-button-in-template)

Comment: Thanks for the comment and I did go through that post before but my functionality is already working. All I want is the genres to show up as buttons. Right now when I inspect and check they are forced to be like <selectors>. I want them to display as buttons.

In this scenario, I don't want to turn each button to a submit button because I already have a submit button upon which I can click and pull the result which works already.

Comment: Also, as hulin003 mentioned in that post, filter.form is a generated HTML, so genres are showing up as <select> <option> </select> now. I want to just show individual genres as separate buttons. The solution by @hulin003 is not working either, when I use that method, I was able to achieve the view but the functionality stopped working.